# Is it possible to overload the operators for the primitive numeric types in scala?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, primitive-types

I created a `ComplexNumber` class. I would like to be able to do something like

`val c = ComplexNumber(1,3);
3 * c;`

but that would require overloading `*` for int, double, etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define an implicit conversion for each type you want to operate on. A convenient place for this is in the companion object.

```
object ComplexNumber {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  implicit def i2cn(i:Int):ComplexNumber = new ComplexNumber(....
}
```

Now `3 * c` will work as long as the `*` method is defined as part of the `ComplexNumber` class.

```
class ComplexNumber(a:Int, b:Int) {
  def *(cn:ComplexNumber): ComplexNumber = ...
}
```